# c# ToFileTime convert to datetime string

Tags: c#, datetime

c# ToFileTime convert to datetime string code?

> 130038578286868465 convert to datetime string ("yyyymmdd H:i:s")

Comment: What is the question? This post really plumbs new depths.

Comment: In fact, the question is understood but not clear.
But I came up here to answer the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.FromFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx). In format string use MM or M for month or mm or m for minutes.

```
 long ft = date1.ToFileTime();
 DateTime date2 = DateTime.FromFileTime(ft);
 string dateString =  date2.ToString("yyyyMMdd H:m:s");
```

Or

```
string dateTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(130038578286868465).ToString("yyyyMMdd H:m:s");
```

**Edit:** To data table cell value, FromFileTime takes long to we have to convert string  to long

```
DateTime.FromFileTime(long.Parse( row["workStartDateTime"].ToString())).ToString("yyyyMMdd H:m:s");
```

Comment: DateTime.FromFileTime(row["workStartDateTime"].ToString()).ToString("yyyymmdd H:i:s"); /errror string convert to filepath?

Comment: FromFileTime takes long not string convert it to long DateTime.FromFileTime(long.Parse( row["workStartDateTime"].ToString())).ToString("yyyymmdd H:i:s");

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s   // error "i"

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime.FromFileTime(myDateTime).ToString("yyyyMMdd H:m:s")`.